# Find intersection in multiple lists

Tags: java, arrays, list, functional-programming, java-stream

Apologies if this was asked before but I couldn't find anything that would be similar to my problem. 
So what I have is a list of objects that contains an `ArrayList` of values.

For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    List<Long> bets = new ArrayList<>();
    ....
}

List<MyClass> myClassList = currencyMap.get(currencyCode);
```

I've been trying something but I believe my solution is somewhat not ok:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myClassList.size(); i++) {
    if (i + 1 >= myClassList .size()) {
        break;
    }
    myClassList.get(i).getBets().retainAll(myClassList.get(i + 1).getBets());
}
```

So what I would like to do now is to find intersection on all `bets` lists in `MyClass` list.

Comment: can you clarify more, about what did you mean by *intersection on all values in MyClass*

Comment: I need to iterate through all list of "bets" and find intersection of values. Hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` for that:

```
myClassList.stream()
    .map(MyClass::getBets)
    .reduce((l1, l2) -> l1.stream()
        .filter(l2::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .orElse(new ArrayList<Long>());
```

The `reduce` operation takes two consecutive lists and produces an intermediate one with elements, that are in both original lists.

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Igor I'm really glad I could help! Have a great day!